# Freeradius - Failed binding to authentication address

Tags: linux, radius

I know that this topics has been discussed many times but all solution/answers found on the mailing list didn't work for me (sure that is my fault!)

When I stop the service and I run `freeradius -xxx` the message is:

```
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Info:  ... adding new socket proxy address * port 47256
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Debug: Listening on authentication address * port 1812
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Debug: Listening on accounting address * port 1813
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Debug: Listening on authentication address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 as server inner-tunnel
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Debug: Listening on proxy address * port 1814
Thu Nov 26 15:14:25 2015 : Info: Ready to process requests.
```

then, I start radius and when I try to do `radtest` I get this error:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# /etc/init.d/freeradius start
[ ok ] Starting FreeRADIUS daemon: freeradius.
root@raspberrypi:~# radtest "John Doe" hello 127.0.0.1 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 126 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
        User-Name = "John Doe"
        User-Password = "hello"
        NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
        NAS-Port = 0
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=126, length=20
```

Looking into a second debug I can see:

```
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Debug: radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Debug: listen {
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Debug:       type = "auth"
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Debug:       ipaddr = *
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Debug:       port = 0
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Error: Failed binding to authentication address * port 1812: Address already in use
Thu Nov 26 15:15:06 2015 : Error: /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf[240]: Error binding to port for 0.0.0.0 port 1812
```

What I'm doing wrong? For me is normal that the port 1812 is busy because `freeradius` is using it!

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify wether using FreeRadius v2.x or v3.x

Comment: See which process is listening on port 1812 with "sudo lsof -i :1812". Note that the Process IDs matter here: it might well be that FreeRADIUS is already running and occupying the port and though you asked it to stop.